# Google maps line square ending instead of rounded in JS API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to change the start and the ending of the line to be squared instead of rounded?

I can see that this is possible in Android Google Maps - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline (Start/end cap)

but I can't find anything about it for JS lib.

I want to draw lines one on the another creating gradient-like impression and rounded corners makes it look worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API Reference for PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolylineOptions), the *strokeLinecap* property is not supported. More precisely, the following are supported:

- *strokeColor*
- *strokeOpacity*
- *strokeWeight*

Additionally, from the (minified) source one can see the linecap hardcoded to *"round"*